# Django Admin of multiple databases

Tags: django, admin, multiple-databases

According to the [1.4 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface) on using Admin with multiple databases, you only need to implement 5 methods in your `ModelAdmin` subclass. I've overridden all 5 in the recommended way. Browsing the database works with no problems.

However, attempt to save an existing record and I get an error claiming that the table doesn't exist in the database - the **default database** for the project, not the one I've specified in the method implementations. In fact, `save_model()` doesn't get called before the error is thrown, so somewhere before it gets that far there's a reference somewhere that isn't successfully getting the "using" for the right database.

Anyone know what's missing? Here's my `ModelAdmin` class:

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    using = "salesdb"

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Tell Django to save objects to the 'other' database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the 'other' database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super(TransactionAdmin, self).queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(TransactionAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(TransactionAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
(1146, "Table 'django_dev._Transactions' doesn't exist")
```

`django_dev` is the default database, not the `sales` database.

Comment: Stepping through it in PyCharm, it appears to be timing related somehow. If I break on the return from the queryset() method, and step over each line until it gets to save_model(), then it looks like it's trying to work (I get an error about truncated data for one of th columns - not sure if that's related). However, if I don't break on queryset(), it never gets to save_model(). In fact, it appears that the offending problem is on line 1034 of options.py (in the latest Django 1.4): form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj) so creating the form SOMETIMES causes the error.

Comment: More information - this appears to be a bug in form validation. It seems that sometimes when trying to validate unique fields the incorrect database is being used to query for uniqueness. I removed the "unique=True" statements on the two fields that had them and now I'm getting past the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently a bug.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19747

The bug has been accepted so I guess that means they confirmed it.